# Using httpclient 4.2.2 Android

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

This is the core of the exception:

```
12-12 10:37:50.090: E/AndroidRuntime(8277): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>
```

I'm using Apache httpclient 4.2.2. However, Android has decided that using its bundled outdated Apache httpclient library is a better option.

How can I avoid this exception?

Just in case: Changing the org.apache namespace is not an option since this exception is being thrown by a closed-source library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, Android has decided that using its bundled outdated Apache httpclient library is a better option.

Google cares about backwards compatibility. <strike>As you are discovering, HttpClient has different APIs with different versions, and so if Google upgraded HttpClient, all existing apps would break.</strike> Google needs to maintain a consistent public API, so that apps written for Android 1.x work on Android 4.x and so on. Google, unfortunately, selected a version of HttpClient that resulted in a rapid break with newer HttpClient versions' public APIs.

> How can I avoid this exception?

Use `jarjar` or the equivalent to refactor your copy of the HttpClient library into a different package name, then use it.

> Changing the org.apache namespace is not an option since this exception is being thrown by a closed-source library.

Then replace the closed-source library with something else. Clearly, if the closed-source library requires HttpClient 4.2.2, then that closed-source library will not work on Android and is not supported by its developer on Android. Even if you were to get past the HttpClient problem (e.g., via a ROM mod -- see below), there may well be other issues with this library with respect to its compatibility with Android.

Or, download the Android source code, replace the HttpClient version with your own, build the revised Android source code, pour the results into a ROM mod, and install the ROM mod on your desired device. Along the way, be sure to test any existing apps to make sure they do not break because of your change (most probably use `HttpUrlConnection`, but they might not).

Comment: > HttpClient has different APIs with different versions, and so if Google upgraded HttpClient, all existing apps would break. This is simply not true. HttpClient 4.x GA releases are fully backward compatible. Google took an arbitrary ALPHA snapshot of HttpClient when rushing Android 1.0 to the market and then expected Apache HttpClient to retain full binary compatibility with it.

Comment: @oleg: "Google took an arbitrary ALPHA snapshot of HttpClient" -- yes, this was definitely unfortunate. "and then expected Apache HttpClient to retain full binary compatibility with it" -- Google did not "expect" Apache to do anything AFAIK. Had Google taken a GA release, then maybe Google could have upgraded HttpClient, for a while, until Apache decided to alter the public API (see: 3.x->4.x). However, my statement that you quoted is still true, as I did not limit "different versions" to GA-only or minor-release-only. That being said, I will try to improve the language in my answer.

Comment: Unless you had been subscribed to the HC dev list at that point of time, you might not know there was an informal agreement that Google would pick up HC 4.0 GA as it became available. Based on that HC development team agreed to prematurely freeze unfinished API and then incrementally improve it gradually deprecating old code.

Comment: That's a very long answer just to say I cannot deploy an app which uses said library.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare One more thing. As far as I remember intention to make a radical API break (3.x->4.x) was made public approx. five years in advance in 2003. It was not done at the drop of a hat.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help, it is a repackaging of HttpClient 4.2.3 for Android that you can reference as a library jar / external library in your project:

http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/